# How to iterate through a "window" of data in a dataset?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a data set in mysql with 150 rows. I have a set of 2 for loops that run math calculations based on some user inputs and the dataset. The code does calculations for 30 row windows, and accumulates the results for each 30 row window in an array.  What I mean is, I do a "cycle" of calculations on rows 0-29, then 1-30, then 2-31, etc... That would result in 120 "cycles".

Right now the for loop is set up like so (there are more fields, I just trimmed the code for simplicity of this question.

```
    $period=30;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
        $data[] = array("Date" => $row['Date'], "ID" => $row['ID']); 
    }
    for($i=0;$i<(count($data)-$window);$i++){
        for($j=0;$j<$window;$j++){
            //do calculations here with $data[]
            $results[$i][$j]= calculations;
        }
    }
```

This works fine for the number of rows I have. However, I opened up the script to a larger dataset (1700 rows) with a different window (360 rows). This means there are exponentially more iterations.  It gave me an out of memory error. Some quick use of memory_get_peak_usage() showed that memory would just continually increase.

I'm starting to think that having the loops search through that data array is extremely laborious, especially when the "window" overlaps on a lot of the "cycles".  Example: Cycle 0 goes through rows 0-29. Cycle 1 goes through rows 1-30. So, both of those cycles share a row of data that they need, but I'm telling PHP to look for the new data each time.

Is there a way to structure this better? I'm getting kind of lost thinking about running these concurrent cycles.

Comment: An answer depends upon what you are doing in the piece of code you left out. If you better describe what you are actually doing, you will get better help.

Comment: I'm just doing basic math with user inputs ($_POST) and the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the array that is blowing memory will be the `$result` array. In your small sample it will be a 2 dimensional array with 150x149 cells. `array( 150, 149 )`. At 144 bytes per element thats 3,218,400 bytes slightly over 3 Meg + remaining bucket space.

In you second larger sample it will be `array(1700,1699)`. At 144 bytes per element thats 415,915,200 bytes, thats slightly over 406Meg + remaining bucket space, just to hold the results of your calculations.

I think you need to ask if you really need to hold all this data. If you really do, you may have to come up with another way of storing it.

I dont see any point attempting the 1000's odd database calls as this will only add to the overhead as you still have to maintain the hugh list of results in an array.

Comment: Huh, I never thought to do the math on the array size. Enlightening. Maybe for the larger data set, it just makes more sense to do a background process that the user can come back to later, and store the info in a database for some amount of hours. 

That's not even counting the fact that I think my real array structure is silly because I defined the arrays weird and just kept running with it.  It's something like $results[0][0][$i][$j]... which probably exponentially makes it bigger. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

## The SQL Way

You can accomplish this by using `LIMIT`

```
$period = 30;
$cycle = 0; //
$query = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $cycle,$period";
```

This will return only the results you need for each cycle.  You will need to loop and increment `$cycle`.  The way you are doing it now is probably better, however.

**This won't loop back however and grab the first of the data, you will have to add additional logic to handle that case.**

Comment: So, do you think its better to be making 120 database calls, rather than doing 1 database call and putting it into an array and searching through that array 120 times? I ask, because if we extrapolate this example up to the larger dataset (1700 rows) ends up making it 1300 or so DB calls.

Comment: Nope, it's probably not better.  However, when you make those calls, the results will be cached, however.